# HealthKit Auth in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I've been building a basic app to collect fitness and other data from health kit in swift, however, I'm having an issue getting authorization to occur

```
class HealthManager {

let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()


func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void)!)
{
    // 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(arrayLiteral:[
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth),
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType),
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight),
    HKObjectType.workoutType()
    ])

// 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:[
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning),
    HKQuantityType.workoutType()
    ])

// 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
{
    let error = NSError(domain: "me.kebabman.healthkit", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"HealthKit is not available in this Device"])
    if( completion != nil )
    {
        completion(success:false, error:error)
    }
    return;
}

// 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
  healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in

    if( completion != nil )
    {
        completion(success:success,error:error)
    }
}
  }

}
```

from another class (my view controller) i'm calling the authoriseHealthKit func - no matter what i change i'm always getting back HealthKit is not available on this device (using the iOS 8.3 simulator)

From reading through the forums this should be working however I can't figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. I think you have to test this on a device.

Comment: hmmm reading through the HealthKit guides you should be able to, i tested  on my iPhone and same error

Comment: Where is the error,??

Comment: HealthKit authorization denied!
Error Domain=me.kebabman.healthkit Code=2 "HealthKit is not available in this Device" UserInfo=0x7fada8ea4120 {NSLocalizedDescription=HealthKit is not available in this Device}

Answer (score 2):

Your IF statement is wrong

This section of code `if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
return error ...
}`

should be

`if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
return error ...
}`

or

`if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
request authorization
...
} else {
return error...
}`